# Buffer cold Observable depending on its events

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, reactivex

I'm struggling to buffer events from an Observable, when buffer size depends on the events themselves, not on just elements count, or some other Observable.

For example, let's events be strings, and I want buffer to be no longer than some number of characters. Here's what I tried to do, and it seems to work fine, but I don't like stateful `SizeCounter` observable. Is there any better way?

```java
public class Test {
  static final int MAX_BUFFER_CHARS = 12;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Observable<String> source = Observable.just("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5");

    Observable<String> shared = source.publish().refCount();

    Observable<Object> boundarySource = shared.flatMapIterable(new SizeCounter());
    Observable<List<String>> buffered = shared.buffer(boundarySource);

    for (List<String> strings : buffered.blockingIterable()) {
      System.out.println(strings);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Emits one-element List if should make a buffer boundary here, and empty List if should continue current buffer.
   */
  static class SizeCounter implements Function<String, List<Object>> {
    int currentBufferSize = 0;

    @Override
    public List<Object> apply(String item) throws Exception {
      if (currentBufferSize + item.length() > MAX_BUFFER_CHARS) {
        // Emit boundary.
        currentBufferSize = item.length();
        return Collections.singletonList(new Object());
      } else {
        // Emit nothing.
        currentBufferSize += item.length();
        return Collections.emptyList();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I prefer to have it single-threaded due to limitations of platform (not a hard requirement). This code works only on single thread anyway, because of stateful `SizeCounter`.

Comment: Unless you implement a custom operator, you'll need a stateful component and a `defer()` around the whole contraption.

Comment: Yep. And I also noticed that built-in `.buffer(<size>)` is also stateful (in BufferExactObserver, also without any `synchronized`), so my code is probably as good as built-in.